# Squid Proxy: ACL error on request by curl

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

my squid.conf(squid3)

```
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
acl localweb src 192.168.199.0/255.255.255.0
http_port 3128 transparent
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localweb
```

my (server squid that runs a dhcp server also) ip is:

eth0 
ip: 192.168.1.10
bcast: 192.168.1.255
netmask: 255.255.255.0

eth1
ip: 192.168.199.1
bcast: 192.168.199.255
netmask: 255.255.255.255

The client command I would like to get working is:

```
curl -x 192.168.1.10:3128 www.google.com
```

The source IP of the client running curl is:

IP 192.168.199.10
bcast 192.168.199.255
netmask 255.255.255.0

In addition in the server I also added the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

The problem is that the following message is returned to the client when making a request:

> 192.168.199.10 TCP_DENIED GET www.google.com
>   Err_Access_Denied by squid localhost (squid  3.1.19)

If i do a simple sudo cat /var/log/squid3/access.log, i see:

> 1 192.168.199.10 TCP_DENIED/403 3629 GET http://www.google.com

And if i do the curl -L -V i get alot of information but to sum it up:

> GET  HTTP/1.1 User agent ***** curl
>   Host: www.google.com  Accept: */* Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>   HTTP 1.0, assume close after body HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden Server:
>   squid/3.1.19
>   X-Cache: Miss from localhost x-Cache-Lookup: NONE from localhost:3128
>   Via: 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.19)
>   Closing connection #0

So I assume my client is reaching the host running squid, but Squid is unable to forward the request.  I had `http_access allow all` , but this didn't work either.

Comment: You have set-up transparent proxy why you are use curl -x?

Comment: well my attempts run all options the curl www.google.com to curl -x none of them worked

Comment: Ok, also not sure if squid works with non-cidr notation.

Try to replace acl localweb src 192.168.199.0/255.255.255.0 with acl localweb src 192.168.199.0/24. Also make sure that you have restarted squid. 

Hm...checked documentation it should work the way you have specified ACL.

Comment: I get on my server the request but they appear denied:

192.168.119.10 TCP_DENIED/403 3629 GET www.google.com

Comment: No, it's not port, it's size of the packet. I am still not sure what's wrong here. Stupid question can you do 'curl google.com' from server with squid itself?

Also it would be useful to make from client side curl -L -v google.com

Comment: from the server with squid when i do :

curl google.com
i get
the normal reply
<h1>Title</h1> blablabla

Comment: from the client i get :

GET HTTP://www.google.com HTTP/1.1
> User agent bla bla curl 
> Host: www.google.com 
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

*HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
<HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
<Server: squid/3.1.19

<X-Cache: Miss from localhost
<x-Cache-Lookup: NONE from localhost:3128

<Via: 1.0 localhost (squi/3.1.19)

Closing connection #0

Comment: Last try from my side, try to change iptables second rule with following:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT  --to-destination 192.168.1.10:3128

Comment: yep i did it , yet not good :( sorry for taking your time and thank you anyway the last error in the access.log is the same of denied the request is getting there but the problems is on the fowarding the reply and request.

Comment: No problem, i hope someone will look into this and provide solution to your problem. I have ran out of ideas right now:) Last advice: try to use tcpdump and debug more hardly this problem. That's what i usually do.

Comment: http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/201304/0112.html

According to this, try to change your hostname on squid server from localhost to something else:) maybe that would help.

Comment: I did it with this THANK GOD !! 

http_access allow all
http_port 3128

i have only this on the server squid.conf

Comment: on the client i did the curl :

curl -x 192.168.1.10:3128 www.google.com

and its all good

Comment: Yep, it's not a transparent proxy you have run now. Gratz that it worked for you now. Still check the link i have provided above, maybe it would help.